# Pandas insert reading_num in a new column

Tags: pandas

I am trying to insert a new column into pandas dataframe.

example dataframe:

```
     reading   other  
0    12         23
1    13         15 
2    23         72
3    9          23
4    10         15
5    67         99 
6    23         68
```

because I take 3 readings each week, i like to add a column:

```
     reading   other   reading_set
0    12         23        1
1    13         15        1
2    23         72        1
3    9          23        2
4    10         15        2
5    67         99        2 
6    23         68        3
```

....

Is there a fast way to do this, if the 3 reading per set can be dynamic will be even better?

thanks

Comment: `df['reading_set'] = (df.index//3)+1` ? or `df['reading_set']=(np.arange(len(df))//3)+1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use numpy func [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html)

```py
df['reading_set'] = df.index.repeat(3)[:len(df)] + 1
df
   reading  other    reading_set
0       12       23    1
1       13       15    1
2       23       72    1
3        9       23    2
4       10       15    2
5       67       99    2
6       23       68    3
```